# Change Flash Player stage quality in AIR apps

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

How do I change the stage quality to improve rendering performance in Flash Player AIR?

[StageQuality](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/StageQuality.html) doesn't seem to have any effect at all. Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using this in the Main() app class constructor:

```
 stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
```

Is there no other way to improve performance in AIR apps?

Comment: As far as I know, stage quality has little to do with performance. What you can try however would be using less for loops, avoiding onEnterFrame logic, grouping unnecessary if conditions etc.

Comment: As far as I know, stage quality has the most to do with performance. Reduce it from HIGH to LOW and practically any app or game will run at least double the speed. Try it.

Comment: Both of you just used gross generalizations to prove your point. Stage quality affecting performance depends entirely on the composition of the content on the stage at any given time; in many cases it can be incredibly useful and in others it can have almost no tangible benefit.

Comment: It would be much more helpful for you to explain what exactly you are doing with AIR, what is not performing properly, etc. StageQuality is not the only option for performance improvement, but not knowing where the issue is makes it difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: as you've found the answer, you should add it as an answer rather than editing your question with the answer.  that way, when someone is searching they are more likely to look at this thread as it will appear to have an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I found the answer in the Adobe [Livedocs](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#quality):

> For content running in Adobe AIR, quality can be set to StageQuality.BEST  or StageQuality.HIGH (and the default value is StageQuality.HIGH).
>
> Attempting to set it to another value has **no effect** (and the property remains unchanged).

Comment: This is true of desktop AIR, but not for mobile AIR (which could be AIR Flash Player on Android but not iOS). Following the above quote on the stage.quality page is: "In the mobile profile of AIR, all four quality settings are available. The default value on mobile devices is StageQuality.MEDIUM." (Perhaps this information has been added since Jarvis posted this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Frame Throttling is just about the BEST way to directly affect performance of an AIR app...

Read this excellent Tutorial from the developer of Destroy Twitter:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/framerate_throttling.html